# In Wordpress, I have passed parameter into the redirect URL with Mailchimp form, but need to pass it through the next page too

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am using Wordpress and I have an email sign up form on my homepage.  When the user types their email in, the mailchimp plugin allows me to pass the variable into the redirect url- example.com/test/?email=hello@world.com.

Now, on this page, I have three buttons using the siteorigin pagebulder widget.  I can input a destination URL in each button, which is 3 different links (one each button), but I still need the email to be passed through these as well.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the "Siteorigin pagebuilder widget" won't give you a an avenue to evaluate PHP code.

Here's a somewhat hacky way to get around that, though:

1. Add a function to the `wp_footer` hook that will dump that `email=...` querystring value to a global javascript variable,
2. Using some more javascript, add that querystring to the 3 links you described in your question.

For example:

```
// functions.php
function pullEmailDataFromQueryString () {
    $email = '';

    if (true === key_exists('email', $_GET)) {
        $email = $_GET['email'];
    }

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">var mc_email = "'.$email.'";</script>';
}

function addEmailDataToButtons() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (undefined !== typeof(mc_email)) {
        var $buttons = jQuery('__CSS-SELECTOR-FOR-YOUR-3-BUTTONS__');

        jQuery.each($buttons, function(i, el) {
            var = $el = jQuery(el);
            $el.attr('href', $el.attr.href() + '?email' = mc_email);
        });
    }
</script>
<?php }

add_action('wp_footer', 'pullEmailDataFromQueryString');
add_action('wp_footer', 'addEmailDataToButtons');
```